# Google calendar api - custom url / ico

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm creating new events in a google calendar ( php API ) and I would like to link a new event to a pdf I created online. This could be a link or ico I can click on in the google calendar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not possible** to customize where your events link to from inside the actual Google Calendar app.

Instead, retrieve your calendar using the API and parse it in your own calendar. You can do whatever you want with it then.

For example, see [this jQuery FullCalendar demo](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/demos/gcal.html) that retrieves the Gcal feed. By changing the `eventClick` method, you should be on your way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        // US Holidays
        events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),

        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

    });

});
```